# how to establish a relationship between node and descendants at specific level with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table with hierarchical data where each row contains an `id`, `parent_id`, `level` which is the depth, and also a path enumeration `hierarchy_hint` which is a plain string with JSON-like formatting. For example:

| id | parent_id | level | hierarchy_hint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 'level1' | '{"level1": "root"}' |
| 2 | 1 | 'level2' | '{"level1": "root", "level2: "shoes"}' |
| 3 | 2 | 'level3' | '{"level1": "root", "level2: "shoes", "level3": "athletic"}' |

(For the sake of example I used integers, but the ids are UUIDs)

I'd like to use `hierarchy_hint` to get all descendants of a given `Node` at a particular `level`. The model already has a self referential relationship established to get direct descendants (`children`). The model looks like:

```
class Node(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('node.id'))
    children = db.relationship('Node')
    level = db.Column(db.String(length=4000), primary_key=False)
    hierarchy_hint = db.Column(db.String(length=200), primary_key=False)
```

I've tried adding to the model:

```
    level_threes = relationship(
        "Node", primaryjoin=and_(
            foreign(hierarchy_hint).like(func.regexp_replace(hierarchy_hint, '}', ',%%')),
            level == 'level3'), viewonly=True)
```

But I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship Node.level_threes could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.
```

I suspect that because I'm modifying the `hierarchy_hint` using `regexp_replace` I should be using a `secondary` table somehow but I'm not experienced enough with SQLAlchemy to know what exactly to do.

I'm open also to alternative suggestions for how to do this using recursive queries or otherwise but I would like to be able to access the property in the same way as I access `children` to avoid refactoring elsewhere.

I'm using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and PostgreSQL.

In plain SQL what I'm trying to do might look like this:

```
with ancestor as (select hierarchy_hint from node where id='2')
select node.id from node, ancestor
    where node.hierarchy_hint and node.level='level4';
```

Here we would expect to get all the `level4` items within the `shoes` tree but no `level4` items from any other trees nor any `level5` etc. items from `shoes`.

Comment: Can you also include the plain SQL you are trying to emulate with SQLAlachemy?  As well as expanding your table to include results that would NOT be returned with this relationship.  It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do with `hierarchy_hint`.

Comment: I think I got an example working but I'm not sure it is exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think I figured out what you are trying to do.  I think you can do something like below.  You are probably aware but you might want to double check that your path in `hierarchy_hint` is deterministic because I'm not sure regular JSON puts the keys in the same order all the time.  It seemed to work with dumps when I tested it though.  I tried to add some data to make sure it wasn't returning everything in the same level.

## Aliased relationship

```py
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))
    parent = relationship('Node', backref='children', remote_side='nodes.c.id')
    level = Column(String(length=200), primary_key=False)
    name = Column(String(length=200), primary_key=False)
    hierarchy_hint = Column(String(length=4000), primary_key=False)

# After class is constructed.
aliased_node = aliased(Node)

# Attach the relationship after class is constructed so we can use alias.
Node.level_threes = relationship(
    aliased_node, primaryjoin=and_(
        aliased_node.hierarchy_hint.like(func.regexp_replace(Node.hierarchy_hint, '}', ',%%')),
        aliased_node.level == 'level3'),
    viewonly=True,
    uselist=True,
    remote_side=[aliased_node.level, aliased_node.hierarchy_hint],
    foreign_keys=Node.hierarchy_hint)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

node_values = [
    ('level1', 'root', {"level1": "root"}),
    ('level2', 'shoes', {"level1": "root", "level2": "shoes"}),
    ('level3', 'athletic shoes', {"level1": "root", "level2": "shoes", "level3": "athletic"}),
]
node_values2 = [
    ('level2', 'shirts', {"level1": "root", "level2": "shirts"}),
    ('level3', 'athletic shirts', {"level1": "root", "level2": "shirts", "level3": "athletic"}),
]

def build_branch(session, parent, node_values):
    nodes = []
    for level, name, value in node_values:
        parent = Node(level=level, name=name, parent=parent, hierarchy_hint=dumps(value))
        session.add(parent)
        nodes.append(parent)
    return nodes

with Session(engine) as session:
    nodes = []
    # Build the original branch.
    nodes.extend(build_branch(session, None, node_values))
    # Now attach another branch below root.
    nodes.extend(build_branch(session, nodes[0], node_values2))
    print(len(nodes))
    session.commit()

    # Print out to check structure
    nodes = session.query(Node).order_by(Node.id).all()
    for node in nodes:
        print(node.id, node.name, node.parent_id, node.level, node.hierarchy_hint)

    shoes = session.query(Node).filter(Node.name == 'shoes').first()
    athletic_shoes = session.query(Node).filter(Node.name == 'athletic shoes').first()
    athletic_shirts = session.query(Node).filter(Node.name == 'athletic shirts').first()
    # Check relationship...
    assert athletic_shoes in shoes.level_threes, "Athletic shoes should be below shoes"
    assert athletic_shirts not in shoes.level_threes, "Athletic shirts should not be below shoes"
```

## Output

```
1 None level1 {"level1": "root"}
2 1 level2 {"level1": "root", "level2": "shoes"}
3 2 level3 {"level1": "root", "level2": "shoes", "level3": "athletic"}
4 3 level2 {"level1": "root", "level2": "shirts"}
5 4 level3 {"level1": "root", "level2": "shirts", "level3": "athletic"}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ian this works! Would you mind explaining why it can't be done without an alias? Is it just that the query becomes too complicated for SQLAlchemy to try to determine?

Comment: @BMcV: I think because it isn't really using a foreign key but I'm not sure.  I think it would be really hard to tell what side of `hierarchy_hint` is the correct side without doing so explicitly with an alias.  I usually would not put something this complicated in a relationship.  I would put it in an ad-hoc query.  Especially since you'd probably want `level=="level3"` to be dynamic.  Pretty cool that it works though as a relationship. I found this but couldn't transform it: [composite-adjacency-lists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/self_referential.html#composite-adjacency-lists)